# Create sql table for matrix and insert csv file into table

Tags: sqlite, csv, matrix

A little new to using sql, but am running into this problem.

I'm trying to create an sql table using sqlite3 for a matrix of months, then insert a csv file into my sql table.

My csv file looks like this with months as both the rows and the columns:

[image: Example Matrix][1]

Comment: The sqlite3 shell program makes it easy: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQLite shell program and create a new database:

```
sqlite3 monthdatabase.sqlite
```

In the shell program create a table for your month data:

```
CREATE TABLE monthdata (
    row_id  INTEGER,
    col01   INTEGER,
    col02   INTEGER,
    col03   INTEGER,
    col04   INTEGER,
    col05   INTEGER,
    col06   INTEGER,
    col07   INTEGER,
    col08   INTEGER,
    col09   INTEGER,
    col10   INTEGER,
    col11   INTEGER,
    col12   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(row_id)
);
```

Check that the (empty) table is there:

```
SELECT * FROM monthdata;
```

The SQLite command line shell has a CSV import mode. It roughly works like this:

```
.import path/to/file.csv tablename
```

The import mode works seamless if the CSV file structure is identical to the table structure.

Depending on the delimiter in your CSV file you have to adjust this first:

```
.separator ";"
.import path/to/monthdata.csv monthdata
```